# AngularJS: Is there a convenient way to show and bind on an element if value is defined?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, ng-bind

I am looking for one line syntax for this:

```
<span ng-if="value">{{value}}</span>
```

Maybe something like:

```
<span ng-bind-if="value"></span>
```

Answer (score 3):

If saving characters is important I would recommend creating a custom directive and handle the logic internally.

```
<span my-hide-if-undefined="value"></span>
```